# How to delete the instance of an object inside a list once a condition is met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm writing a text based game as an exercise. I have the GenerateEnemies function which creates some random goblins and places them in the CurrentEnemy list.

Using the Attack function, I can make the hero attack a goblin in the CurrentEnemy list, decreasing its HP.

What I want to happen is that when an enemy's health reaches below 0, it dies. I put in the exception "if self.HP < 0: del(self)" but that doesn't work.

What is the proper syntax to achieve the intended behavior? Also, if the object is deleted, what would happen to the things inside CurrentEnemy? Would everything shift or would there be nothing in the index the object was once in?

```
import random
CurrentEnemy = []

class Monster(object):

    def __init__(self, Name, HP, Damage):
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = HP
        self.Damage = Damage

    **if self.HP < 0:
        del(self)**

class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, Name, HP, Damage):
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = HP
        self.Damage = Damage

def GenerateEnemies():
    NumberEnemies = random.randint(0,5)
    del CurrentEnemy[:]

    i=0
    while i < (NumberEnemies+1):
        TempMonster = Monster("Goblin", random.randint(15,20), random.randint(1,3))
        CurrentEnemy.append(TempMonster)
        i = i + 1

    i=0
    while i in range(0, len(CurrentEnemy)):
        print("Goblin " + str(i) + " HP: " + str(CurrentEnemy[i].HP))
        print("Goblin " + str(i) + " Damage: " + str(CurrentEnemy[i].Damage))
        i = i + 1


def GenerateHero(HeroName, HeroHP, HeroDamage):
    return Hero(HeroName, HeroHP, HeroDamage)

MyHero = GenerateHero("Bob", 100, 10)

def Attack(Attacker, Defender):
    Defender.HP = Defender.HP - Attacker.Damage
```

Comment: Use `snake_case` for God's sake

Comment: Do you find snake_case easier to read than CamelCase? Or is it just that it is more widely accepted as the norm?

Comment: This is a coding convention ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)) : in Python, classes names should be written `UpperCamelCase`, variables, functions, and methods in `snake_case`. And yes, when you know that the developer respects these conventions, the code is instantly faster to read (well, it is to me at least) ; in Python you can do operations on classes like you do on functions and variables, thus good naming with good case makes a disambiguation and the code gets more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting from a list is expensive, use a set() instead. And it has various utility functions to delete the object like s.add() and s.discard().

Now regarding your question:

del(self) only deletes the reference to the local variable self within the class, not the whole object.

And if you want to delete the object, you have to delete it from the list container in which you have stored it.

Comment: I ended up using a set and adding a check in the attack function to see if the Defender that was damaged was less than 0 HP:

def Attack(Attacker, Defender):
    Defender.HP = Defender.HP - Attacker.Damage
    if Defender.HP < 0:
            CurrentEnemy.remove(Defender)

Comment: Great!! glad that helped. :)

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by saying that deleting from a list is "expensive" ?

Comment: In brief, the internal implementations of list() and set() in python are different. list() usually stores that can be numerically indexed, like an array. So, when you try to delete data from the middle of the list, it shifts all the data on the right of the element to one index. This is a heavy operation which takes O(n).
whereas
In set(), data you stored get hashed by a hashing algorithm, and it doesn't support indexes and you cannot store mutable types to a set(). So, when you make a query to delete, it generates the hash and find the data in one sweep, if exists taking O(1) complexity.